# Truck burning through a lot of gas

Tags: ford, fuel-system, troubleshooting, fuel-consumption, f-150

**Vehicle Information:**

2006 Ford F150 4WD with the 5.4L

**Problem:**

On the way to work I noticed that the truck was "burning" a lot of gas.  As I drove, (at a normal speed - 60 mph) I noticed that the **Miles to Empty** display **dropped 4 miles within** a distance that I know to be roughly **1 mile**

I thought that there might have been something wrong with the engine or the fuel system; however,

- the truck has not produced any error lights (yet)
- I'm still getting the same average mpg as always (~16 mpg)

I then thought that I must have a leak, so I checked under the truck at a gas station. I checked for leaks dripping to the ground both while the truck was running as well as when it was not.  I did not see any signs of gas on the ground

---

If anyone has seen a problem like this before and knows where I should start looking, or you can shed some light on the situation it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realize, the "Miles to Empty" is just a best guess by the computer as to how many miles the vehicle can drive on the remaining fuel in the tank. The computer could have just been adjusting itself to compensate for some unseen factor. I'd suggest you just pay attention to what you are actually putting into the truck and the amount of miles you're getting from your tank of gas and see if it equates to what you are thinking the mileage should be.

Comment: @Paulster2 you should post this as an answer... Also makes me think we should have a "stickies" area for common repeated questions, question for meta perhaps?

Comment: When was the last time the spark plugs were changed? They are only good for 40K miles max on that year model.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the information. I'm aware that the numbers are based on the computer calculations, so I wonder if it could have been compensating for something like bad gas or something similar.  Also, when I drove back from work everything was normal and the display numbers were what I expected them to be.

Comment: @Moab Yeah... they were changed out at around 90k and I'm at 145k right now so it is time to change them.

Comment: @JacobCaldwell way over due.